# JQuery - post array and write to file on php

Tags: php, jquery

I write test code, that post array on php page. Php page need write this array to file to check data.

JQuery:

```
    $("#Trash").click(function () {
    $.post("tests.php",
    {'ids[]': ArrayCheckBox},
        function(result){
            window.location = 'tests.php';
         }
      );
    });
```

In tests.php i tried to parse:

```
            $s = array();
            foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
              if (is_array($v)) {
                if ($v=='ids[]')
                  array_push($s, $v[0]);
              }
            }

            $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/test2.txt';
            $current = file_get_contents($file);
            $current .= implode(', ', $s); 
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

But this code write only "1" every time. How fixed it?

Comment: Can you output the content of $_POST or $v ?? What does your $s variable look like when you save it into your file (after youyr foreach loop) ?

Comment: maybe send it as json and not pass ArrayCheckBox reference?

Comment: Not a JQuery expert but I would suggest that the use of square brackets in the name when POSTing is so it can be interpreted by PHP as an array before passing on to your PHP script. So the name of the $_POST item will be 'ids'. The whole if($v == 'ids[]') ... looks wrong to me. Surely you need something like if (!strcmp($k,'ids')) ... or using the less reliable "==", if ($k == 'ids') ... in your foreach $k will hold the element name/key and $v the value.

Comment: I also wondered why you appear to only be interested in the first element of your checkbox array ($v[0]). should you not be using a foreach to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 1):

So, your javascript looks pretty close.  The only thing that looks strange to me is that you used square brackets after ids[], I guess since it's an array -- you don't need to do that.

```
$("#Trash").click(function () {
    $.post("tests.php",
        {'ids': ArrayCheckBox},
        function(result){
            window.location = 'tests.php';
        }
    );
});
```

But I'm also a little confused about your variable ArrayCheckBox -- what is that supposed to contain?  Is that an array of values you are ready to post?  Or is that an actual Dom Object like a checkbox?  If so, you need to get the raw data out first before you post it.

Moving on -- your PHP code confuses me a bit.

Once your javascript hits tests.php, PHP will kick off with your data in $_POST, it will looks something like this: array('ids'=>array('1','2','3',...)).

What do you want your file to look like?  One of the easiest ways to take that whole array and write it to a file would be to use json:

```
<?php
$json = json_encode($_POST);
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/test2.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $json);
?>
```

It looks like you were trying to check the data against what was already there, is that right?  If so, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
$json = json_encode($_POST);
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/test2.txt';
$current_contents = file_get_contents($file);
if ($current_contents == $json) {
    echo "Data is still the same as what was already there.";
}
else {
    echo "Data has changed."
}
?>
```

Let me know if you have any more questions.